# How to understand the master and worker processes---R package "parallel"?

Tags: r, rparallel

As I tried to understand the documentation of the `R` package `parallel`, I encountered this question as I read some lines of codes on Page 8 in the [package's documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf). I have copied the code in the following. Please note that `mc` is just equal to `2`.

```
# mc = 2
cl <- makeCluster(mc)
cd4.rg <- function(data, mle) MASS::mvrnorm(nrow(data), mle$m, mle$v)
cd4.mle <- list(m = colMeans(cd4), v = var(cd4))
clusterExport(cl, c("cd4.rg", "cd4.mle"))
junk <- clusterEvalQ(cl, library(boot)) # discard result
clusterSetRNGStream(cl, 123)
res <- clusterEvalQ(cl, boot(cd4, corr, R = 500,
+                   sim = "parametric", ran.gen = cd4.rg, mle = cd4.mle))
library(boot) # needed for c() method on master
cd4.boot <- do.call(c, res)
boot.ci(cd4.boot, type = c("norm", "basic", "perc"),
+                   conf = 0.9, h = atanh, hinv = tanh)
stopCluster(cl)
```

In Line 5, the command `library(boot)` has been evaluated on `cl`, but in line 8 `library(boot)` is run again and the author says it is needed for `c()` method on master.

My original understanding is that: `makeCluster(mc)` creates two worker processes, and the master process is one of them. Now it looks that each of the workers created by `makeCluster(mc)` is different from the master process. And thus `library(boot)` has to be run on the master process. Am I right on this?

If I have an 8-core CPU, does this mean that creating more than seven (*>7*) worker processes is totally non-useful? Thank you.

Comment: According to [this post][1], the master and worker processes do be different. My question remains regarding how many work processes I can meaningfully create. 


  [1]: http://www.quantide.com/R/ramarro-chapter-09/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system, makeCluster(2) can be seen to create 2 *additional* R processes (I'm on Windows and can see them in Resource Monitor). So the "workers" appear to be different from, and additional to, the "master" process.

As regards the libraries, a quick way to check is to ask each worker for its `loadedNamespaces()`. The below transcript shows this for the example of the `foreach` package  being loaded on the two workers, with the `loadedNamespaces()` for the workers and the master before and after.

Since only the worker processes are used to execute the expression by `clusterEvalQ`, increasing the number of workers to a maximum of 8 would seem sensible at face value. Real performance will depend on other factors like the number of logical cores available on your 8-core system, what each core is doing in your processing, and what else is happening on the system at the time, ...

Transcript:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
loadedNamespaces() # get loaded namespaces on master
# [1] "base"      "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"
clusterEvalQ(cl, loadedNamespaces()) # get loaded namespaces on workers
# [[1]]
# [1] "base"      "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"    
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "base"      "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"    
# 
invisible( clusterEvalQ(cl, library(foreach)) ) # load foreach on workers
loadedNamespaces() # check master
# [1] "base"      "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"
clusterEvalQ(cl, loadedNamespaces()) # check workers
# [[1]]
#  [1] "base"      "codetools" "datasets"  "foreach"   "graphics"  "grDevices" "iterators" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"    
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] "base"      "codetools" "datasets"  "foreach"   "graphics"  "grDevices" "iterators" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"    
# 
library(foreach) # load foreach on master
# foreach: simple, scalable parallel programming from Revolution Analytics
# Use Revolution R for scalability, fault tolerance and more.
# http://www.revolutionanalytics.com
loadedNamespaces() # check again
# [1] "base"      "codetools" "datasets"  "foreach"   "graphics"  "grDevices" "iterators" "methods"   "parallel"  "stats"     "utils"    
stopCluster(cl) # tidy up
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, Chriss :)